# How to solve "ebook-convert" is not installed?

Tags: pdf, gitbook, calibre

I want to convert .md into PDFs, and I followed https://toolchain.gitbook.com/ebook.html:

> Download the Calibre application. After moving the calibre.app to your Applications folder create a symbolic link to the ebook-convert tool:
>
> $ sudo ln -s ~/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert /usr/bin

Then I got this:

```
HF:The-North-Book wonderful$ sudo ln -s ~/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert /usr/bin
Password:
ln: /usr/bin/ebook-convert: File exists
HF:The-North-Book wonderful$ PATH
-bash: PATH: command not found
HF:The-North-Book wonderful$ gitbook pdf ./ ./mybook.pdf
info: 7 plugins are installed 
info: 6 explicitly listed 
info: loading plugin "highlight"... OK 
info: loading plugin "search"... OK 
info: loading plugin "lunr"... OK 
info: loading plugin "sharing"... OK 
info: loading plugin "fontsettings"... OK 
info: loading plugin "theme-default"... OK 
info: found 26 pages 
info: found 0 asset files 

InstallRequiredError: "ebook-convert" is not installed.
Install it from Calibre: https://calibre-ebook.com
```

While I do have installed calibre 2, so I don't know where the problem is.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 13):

You can install it with **homebrew**:

```
brew install --cask calibre
```

If you don't have cask:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask
```

Then just use it normally

```
 ebook-convert ~/path_to/file.pdf ~/new_file_path/gen_file.pdf (options)
```

Answer (score 2):

As of 2021, the answer to this question for me was that instead of

`brew tap homebrew/cask`

then

`brew install --cask calibre`